# Filling Fill incomplete in ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, filling

```
data = {{0., 0., 0}, {0.12, 0.04, 2}, {0.24, 0.08, 4}, {0.36, 0.11, 
    6}, {0.47, 0.15, 8}, {0.59, 0.19, 10}, {0.71, 0.23, 12}, {0.83, 
    0.26, 14}, {0.95, 0.3, 16}, {1.07, 0.34, 18}, {1.21, 0.38, 
    20}, {1.38, 0.41, 22}, {1.78, 0.45, 24}, {2.84, 0.49, 26}, {3.45, 
    0.52, 28}, {3.88, 0.56, 30}, {4.33, 0.6, 32}, {4.79, 0.64, 
    34}, {5.25, 0.64, 36}, {5.89, 0.3, 38}, {6.16, 0.68, 40}, {6.51, 
    0.84, 42}, {6.89, 0.98, 44}, {7.27, 1.14, 46}, {7.67, 1.39, 
    48}, {8.07, 1.95, 50}, {8.47, 5.3, 52}, {8.89, 5.82, 54}, {9.3, 
    6.14, 56}, {9.71, 6.48, 58}, {10.11, 6.9, 60}, {10.52, 7.56, 
    62}, {10.92, 8.18, 64}, {11.32, 8.55, 66}, {11.72, 8.86, 
    68}, {12.13, 9.16, 70}, {12.53, 9.46, 72}, {12.93, 9.77, 
    74}, {13.33, 10.07, 76}, {13.73, 10.38, 78}};

ListLinePlot[data[[;; , {#, 3}]] & /@ {1, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, Frame -> 1]
```

My code gives this

[image]

but I want it look like this

[image]

Comment: You can use `Filling -> {1 -> Top, 2 -> {Top, White}}` for this particular plot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Reverse points around y=x axis (flip y-x coordintaes) to get correct filling
- But now you plot is flipped - so flip again around y=x with GeometricTransformation

Here it is:

```
pl = ListLinePlot[(Reverse /@ data[[All, {#, 3}]]) & /@ {1, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}];
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[pl[[1, 2]], ReflectionTransform[{-1, 1}]], Frame -> True, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 ... there is a german saying: "Von hinten durch die Brust ins Auge" which kinda fits here :-)

Comment: @YvesKlett Yep, "From behind through the chest into the eye" ;-)

Comment: In version 7 I need `Normal[pl][[1]]` in place of `pl[[1, 2]]` for this to work. (+1)

Comment: We have a similar saying: "Around your ass into your pocket."

Answer (score 7):

I like the solution panda-34 gave in a comment on the question. It is simple and gets the job done

```
ListLinePlot[data[[;; , {#, 3}]] & /@ {1, 2},
  Filling -> {{1 -> Top}, {2 -> {Top, White}}},
  Frame -> True]
```

However, if there is some reason why it would be undesirable to have the upper left region of the plot rectangle filled with opaque white, you can get the results you want by appending a data point to the data for the upper curve that extends it to the far right of the plot rectangle but puts it outside the plot range.

```
Module[{d1, d2},
  {d1, d2} = data[[;; , {#, 3}]] & /@ {1, 2};
  AppendTo[d2, {data[[-1, 1]], 2 + data[[-1, -1]]}];
  ListLinePlot[{d1, d2},
    PlotRange -> {0, data[[-1, -1]]},
    PlotRangePadding -> {.25, 2},
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
    Frame -> True]]
```

Both of the above expressions produce the desired plot when evaluated:

[image: plot.png]