# Filling a curve to a vertical axis: Q#2

Tags: plotting, filling

I found an elegant solution to my problem on this site in the answer No 2 to the post [Filling a curve to a vertical axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33443/filling-a-curve-to-a-vertical-axis). Consider the following example:

```
lst = Table[{1.3 - Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.4 - Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.05}];

lst2 = Table[{1.5 - 0.8 Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.9 - 0.3 Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 
    1, 0.05}];

plt = ListLinePlot[{lst, lst2}, Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic
  , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

It yields
[image]

Applying to this plot function

```
fillVertical[plot_, x0_ : 0.] := 
  plot /. Line[
     p_] :> {{Opacity[0.2], 
      Polygon[p~Join~{{N@x0, p[[-1, 2]]}, {N@x0, p[[1, 2]]}}]}, 
     Line[p]};
```

as proposed in [Filling a curve to a vertical axis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33443/filling-a-curve-to-a-vertical-axis) gives almost what I need:

```
fillVertical[plt, 0.1]
```

[image]

To become even more happy, I would like to have an option. e.g., to switch off vertical filling for second, third, e.t.c. curves, i.e., for `lst2` in the example above. Second desired option is to extend filing to the bottom and to the top of the picture. My knowledge of Wolfram Language is insufficient to find how I could do that.

**Update**

Please note that I need a solution which would preserve style of plot markers and correct plot legends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ClearAll[addHorizontalFilling]

addHorizontalFilling[pos_ : All, pr_ : Automatic] := 
  Module[{xyr = pr /. Automatic -> 
      Transpose @ Charting`get2DPlotRange[If[Head @ # === Legended, First@#, #]],
    xyrnp = pr /. Automatic -> 
      Transpose @ PlotRange[If[Head @ # === Legended, First @ #, #]]},
    xyr = {Clip[#, First @ xyrnp], #2} & @@ xyr;
    ReplaceAt[#, l_Line :>
      Module[{cl = Transpose[{Clip[#, First @ Transpose @ xyr], 
             Clip[#2, Last @ Transpose @ xyr]} & @@ Transpose[l[[1]]]]}, 
       {l, Opacity[.2], 
        Polygon[Join[{xyr[[1]], {cl[[1, 1]], xyr[[1, 2]]}}, cl, 
         {{0, xyr[[2, 2]]} + {cl[[-1, 1]], 0}, {xyr[[1, 1]], xyr[[2, 2]]}}]]}], 
      Position[#, _Line][[pos]]]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{lst, lst2}, Joined -> True, 
   PlotMarkers -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"list 1", "list 2"}];
```

Add horizontal filling to all curves (default):

```
addHorizontalFilling[] @ llp
```

[image]

Add filling to the first curve only:

```
addHorizontalFilling[1] @ llp
```

[image]

Add filling to the second curve only:

```
addHorizontalFilling[2] @ llp
```

[image]

Use the second argument to specify the rectangle coordinates to be filled:

```
addHorizontalFilling[All, {{.1, .5}, {1.2, 2.2}}] @ llp
```

[image]

Add filling to curves 1 and 3:

```
pltb = addHorizontalFilling[{1, 3}] @
 ListLinePlot[{lst, lst2, Threaded[{-.1, 1}] + lst}, 
  Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"list 1", "list 2", "list 3"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, All}, {0, All}}]
```

[image]

```
hatchFillings = HatchFilling[#, 2, 10] & /@ {Pi/4, -Pi/4, Pi};

ReplaceAll[{l_Line, a___, p_Polygon} :>
   {l, a, p, Opacity[1],
    Last[hatchFillings = RotateLeft[hatchFillings]], p}] @ pltb
```

[image]

Comment: Solution of @kglr is excellent from all points of view. Unfortunately, it assumes that option `PlotRangeClipping`  is set to `False` which is not my case.  Therefore, currently I am using a hybrid of solutions proposed by @kglr and @DanielHuber. Is there a method to put some text outside `PlotRange` without setting  `PlotRangeClipping` to `False`? Or to impose some window for filling?

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov, please see the updated version

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thank you so much. Nevertheless, at the moment I am using my own solution which is less difficult to understand. I'll post my answer soon.

Comment: It seems that this method fails in Mathematica 13.2 for plots without `PlotLegeds`, `get2DPlotRange[If[Head @ # == Legended, First@#, #]]` does not work as expected.

Comment: @IgorKotelnikov, thank you for the catch.  I fixed the problem (`Head @ # == Legended` should be `Head @ # === Legended` )

Comment: Thank you. It works!

Answer (score 3):

To apply filling only to the first curve, you make a plot of the first curve with filling and a second plot withoutfilling of the rest of the curves and show them together:

```
lst1 = Table[{1.3 - Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.4 - Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 1, 
    0.05}];
lst2 = Table[{1.5 - 0.8 Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.9 - 0.3 Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 
    1, 0.05}];

pl1 = ListLinePlot[{lst1}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];
pl2 = ListLinePlot[{lst2}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];

fillVertical[plot_, x0_ : 0.] := 
  plot /. Line[
     p_] :> {{Opacity[0.2], 
      Polygon[p~Join~{{N@x0, p[[-1, 2]]}, {N@x0, p[[1, 2]]}}]}, 
     Line[p]};

Show[fillVertical[pl1, 0.1], pl2]
```

[image]

To make filling to the bottom and top, you must split the data so that the function is unique. Then you plot the lower part with filling to the bottom and the upper part with filling to the top:

```
lst11 = Table[{1.3 - Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.4 - Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 1/2, 
    0.05}];
lst12 = Table[{1.3 - Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.4 - Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 1/2, 1, 
    0.05}];
pl11 = ListLinePlot[{lst11}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Bottom];
pl12 = ListLinePlot[{lst12}, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> Top];
Show[{pl11, pl12}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what i want. I have used separate filling for upper and lower branches in the past. I want a better solution which would keep style of markers and correct plot legends. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted solution by @kglr although still use my own version:

```
fillVertical6[plt_, pos_ : All] := Module[{x0, x1, y0, y1}
  ,
  {{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}} = 
   Charting`get2DPlotRange[
    If[Head@# == Legended, First@#, #] &[plt]];
  (*Print[];*)
  ReplaceAt[#, l_Line :> {l, Opacity[.25]
       , Polygon[Join[
         {{x0, y0},
            {x1, y0}, {x1, #[[2]]}} &@( l[[1, 1]])
         , {{x1, #[[2]]}} &@( l[[1, 1]])
         , l[[1]]
         , {#, {x1, #[[2]]}, {x1, y1}, {x0, y1}} &@(l[[1, -1]])]]}, 
     Position[#, _Line][[pos]]] &[plt]
  ]


lst = Table[{1.3 - Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.4 - Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 1, 0.05}];
lst2 = Table[{1.5 - 0.8 Sin[\[Pi] t], 1.9 - 0.3 Cos[\[Pi] t]}, {t, 0, 
    0.7, 0.05}];

plt = ListLinePlot[{lst, lst2, Threaded[{-.1, 1}] + lst}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> Automatic
  , PlotRange -> {{0.1, Full}, {0, Full}}
  , Prolog -> {Text[Style["lbl", Blue, 16], 
     Scaled[{0.5, 1.04}], {0, 1}]}
  , PlotRangeClipping -> False]

fillVertical6[plt, {1, 3}]
```

[image]

This is a bit different from @kglt's solution:

```
ClearAll[addHorizontalFilling]
addHorizontalFilling[pos_ : All, pr_ : Automatic] := 
  Module[{xyr = 
      pr /. Automatic -> 
        Transpose@
         Charting`get2DPlotRange[If[Head@# == Legended, First@#, #]], 
     xyrnp = pr /. 
       Automatic -> 
        Transpose@PlotRange[If[Head@# == Legended, First@#, #]]}, 
    xyr = {Clip[#, First@xyrnp], #2} & @@ xyr;
    ReplaceAt[#, 
     l_Line :> 
      Module[{cl = 
         Transpose[{Clip[#, First@Transpose@xyr], 
             Clip[#2, Last@Transpose@xyr]} & @@ 
           Transpose[l[[1]]]]}, {l, Opacity[.2], 
        Polygon[Join[{xyr[[1]], {cl[[1, 1]], xyr[[1, 2]]}}, 
          cl, {{0, xyr[[2, 2]]} + {cl[[-1, 1]], 0}, {xyr[[1, 1]], 
            xyr[[2, 2]]}}]]}], Position[#, _Line][[pos]]]] &;

addHorizontalFilling[{1, 3}]@plt
```

[image]